# Mixing white to a color

Tags: python, colors

I have a set of colors specified in RBG and CMYK. I want to mix a certain amount of white (given in percent) to these colors. How can I do this based on the representations available? Can someone recommend a package that can help me with this kind of color conversions?

Comment: At least for RGB colors I think you could use the [colorsys module](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html) and convert to HSL, change the lightness, and go back to rgb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have RGB values r, g and b between 0 and 255 and want to mix them with x% white, you can calculate

```
r' = ((100 - x) * r + x * 255) / 100
g' = ((100 - x) * g + x * 255) / 100
b' = ((100 - x) * b + x * 255) / 100
```

If you need it to be efficient, there are ways of doing this with efficient bit operations.

Answer (score 1):

Find the difference between the current color and the target color for each color channel.  Calculate your percentage of that difference.  Add this to the original value, and you're done.

For example, mixing RGB(255,127,0) with RGB(255,255,255) (white) at 75% gives you RGB(255, 223, 191)

- R: 255-255 = 0 * .75 = 0 + 255 = 255
- G: 255 - 127 = 128 * .75 = 96 + 127 = 224
- B: 255 - 0 = 255 * .75 = 191 + 0 = 191)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your colors to HSL with [this lib](http://code.google.com/p/python-colormath/), then modify the L component and go back to your previous representation, RGB or CMYK.